# Error while installing Microsoft SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005

I was trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2005 on my Windows 7 pc. When I tried to install it, it tells me that I have a newer version installed on my pc. So, I checked that Microsoft Sharepoint 2010 installed some sql server 2008 tools for me.

I decided to uninstall SharePoint 2010(which I wasn't using) and then tried to install MS SQL Server 2005 again. This threw me the following exception:

```
Error 1603 installing microsoft sql server setup support files
```

Searching on Google I found this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916760 but it's not my case actually.

Any help will be appreciated. I really need this to continue working.

Comment: I'd recommend trying checking on ServerFault.com. By the way, I also installed SharePoint 2010 on a server, prior to SQL Server 2008. Had to install SQL Server 2008 on another machine as apparently some component of Sharepoint 2010 beta is newer and causes issues. Didn't dig too deep into it, but in hindsight: First install SQL Server, then SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this might be useful
http://vivekthangaswamy.blogspot.com/2008/05/none-of-selected-features-can-be.html

Answer (score 0):

Turn on all the Windows Features for IIS - this fixed the problem for me.

This is done via Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.